# Trying to get an update every time a task completes

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

My application downloads data from various URLs. I would like to know every time a URL download completes – succeeds or fails. For this I have following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var URLsToProcess = new List<string>
        {
             "http://www.microsoft.com",
             "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
             "http://www.google.com",
             "http://www.apple.com",
             "http://www.ebay.com",
             "http://www.oracle.com",
             "http://www.gmail.com",
             "http://www.amazon.com",
             "http://www.outlook.com",
             "http://www.yahoo.com",
             "http://www.amazon124.com",
             "http://www.msn.com"
         };


     var tasks = URLsToProcess.Select(uri => DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(uri))).ToArray();

     while (tasks.Any())
     {
         try
         {
             //Task.WaitAll(tasks);
             int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
             Console.WriteLine("{0} has completed", tasks[index].AsyncState.ToString());
             tasks = tasks.Where(t => t != tasks[index]).ToArray();
             break;
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             foreach (var t in tasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted))
                 Console.WriteLine("{0} has failed", t.AsyncState.ToString());
             // handle exception/report progress...
             tasks = tasks.Where(t => t.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted).ToArray();
         }
     }   
 }

 static Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address)
 {
     TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(address);
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
     {
         if (args.Error != null)
             tcs.SetException(args.Error);
         else if (args.Cancelled)
             tcs.SetCanceled();
         else
             tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
     };
     client.DownloadStringAsync(address);
     return tcs.Task;
 }
```

However I only get one URL in the output. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extraneous `break` in your `while` loop:

```
while (tasks.Any())
{
    try
    {
        //Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has completed", tasks[index].AsyncState.ToString());
        tasks = tasks.Where(t => t != tasks[index]).ToArray();
        //break;  // NOTE: extraneous break that I have commented out
    }
```

With the `break` *as you had it*, your code produced the following output on my machine:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/ has completed
```

With the `break` *commented out* as I showed above, your code produced the following output on my machine:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/ has completed
http://www.apple.com/ has completed
http://www.oracle.com/ has completed
http://www.amazon124.com/ has completed
http://www.google.com/ has completed
http://www.msn.com/ has completed
http://www.stackoverflow.com/ has completed
http://www.amazon.com/ has completed
http://www.ebay.com/ has completed
http://www.gmail.com/ has completed
http://www.outlook.com/ has completed
http://www.yahoo.com/ has completed
```